# tornado oauth queries (twitter)

Tags: oauth, tornado

I am using tornado framework to use the Twitter API. I am not understanding why I am getting a callback url with the value of next in it

```
auth/login?next=%2F%3Foauth_token%3D
```

I understand that /auth/login is setup by me during AuthLoginHandler. But I am not understanding what is setting next token inside the url. This makes my other argument

```
self.get_argument('oauth_token', None)
```

return None.

I know that we can still parse the url the get the oauth_token, but any insights into how TwitterMixin or default Oauth class of tornado is doing this. I am a newbie to Tornado

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You can ignore the 'next' argument until you get your core code working.

'next' is an extra parameter so you can forward the user to to the original page you asked for like this:

```
self.redirect(self.get_argument('next', '/'))
```

The 'next' param is added in the [request handler here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/_modules/tornado/web.html#authenticated) after a call to get_current_user has returned None. [ie user is not logged in]

[The Tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/auth.html#twitter)  describe how to write a handler for Twitter.